# Javascript cannot display countdown timer which also starts on button click

Tags: javascript

I am creating a countdown timer and I managed to get the timer to display and countdown, but it starts automatically when the page loads. I would like to prevent this. I know how to add an event handler I just can't work out how to stop it loading automatically.

Edited as I forgot to copy in a a div with countdown as #id.

```js
((d) => {
  let start = d.getElementById("start");
  let stop = d.getElementById("stop");
  let reset = d.getElementById("reset");

  let timerFormat = (s) => {
    return (s - (s %= 60)) / 60 + (9 < s ? ":" : ":0") + s;
  };

  let counter;
  let startTime = 1500;

  timer = () => {
    startTime--;
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timerFormat(startTime);
    if (startTime === 0) clearInterval(counter);
  };
  counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

  startHandler = () => {
    let el = document.getElementById("start");
    el.addEventListener("click", counter);
  };

})(document);
```

```html
<div id="countdown"></div>
<button class="btn" id="start">Start</button>
<button class="btn" id="stop">Stop</button>
<button class="btn" id="reset">Reset</button>
```

Comment: You don't have an element with an id="countdown" in your html body to put anything in.

Comment: Edited and added in the div.

Comment: `counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);` This line is starting the timer. When you call `setInterval`, the interval starts immediately. You don't want to init that until the button is clicked.

Comment: So I placed the setInterval inside the timer function, it starts on click when I called the timer function, but it is also now doubling each second

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply have to adde event handlers to the buttons like so:

```js
 start.onclick = ()=>{
        counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);
      }
      stop.onclick = () => {
        clearInterval(counter);
        counter =  undefined;
      }
      
      reset.onclick = ()=>{
        startTime = 1500;
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timerFormat(startTime);
      }
```

live demo:

```js
((d) => {
  let start = d.getElementById("start");
  let stop = d.getElementById("stop");
  let reset = d.getElementById("reset");

  let timerFormat = (s) => {
    return (s - (s %= 60)) / 60 + (9 < s ? ":" : ":0") + s;
  };

  let counter;
  let startTime = 1500;

  timer = () => {
    startTime--;
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timerFormat(startTime);
    if (startTime === 0) clearInterval(counter);
  };
  start.onclick = ()=>{
    counter = counter  || setInterval(timer, 1000);
  }
  stop.onclick = () => {
    clearInterval(counter);
    counter =  undefined;
  }
  
  reset.onclick = ()=>{
    startTime = 1500;
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timerFormat(startTime);
  }

})(document);
```

```html
<div id="countdown"></div>
<button class="btn" id="start">Start</button>
<button class="btn" id="stop">Stop</button>
<button class="btn" id="reset">Reset</button>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I've been shuffling lines of code around for hours now with  no results.

Comment: after `clearInterval(counter);` you should add this line `counter =  undefined;` and replace `counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);` with `counter = counter ? counter : setInterval(timer, 1000);` to prevent using multiple intervals

Comment: The stop button in your example here is not stopping the timer on the page.

Comment: @daddygames what do you mean it will stop removing more seconds?

Comment: the example is working now. The stop button was not stopping the countdown for me when I made my previous comment.